# Does だーれ mean the same as だれ?

Tags: words

Saw this in a children's book:
「見つけたのは　だーれ？」
Is this essentially the same as 「だれ」?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, 「だーれ」 means the same thing as 「だれ」.  The important questions, however, are "when" and "with whom" we say 「だーれ」 rather than 「だれ」.

When talking to babies and toddlers, we tend to elongate the first syllables in question words ***if the question words are placed at the END of sentences***.

If you do not follow this, you *might possibly* end up looking slightly cold or uninterested to the toddler, but if you ever do it with an adult or a kid over 7 or 8, you will look incredibly weird.

So, we say:

・なーに/なあに

・どーこ/どおこ

・どーれ/どおれ

・なーぜ/なあぜ

・いーつ/いいつ

, etc.

Thus, native speakers tend to say to toddlers:

「クマさんは**どこ**にいますか？」 ← No elongation

「**どこ**にクマさんはいますか？」 ← No elongation

「クマさんがいるのは**どおこ**だ？」 ← **Elongation**

To use your example sentence,

「**だれ**が見つけたの？」 ← No elongation

「見つけたのは　**だーれ**？」 ← **Elongation**

Rhythm, intonation, syllable lengths, etc., though they are rarely discussed here for obvious reasons, are of utmost importance in Japanese.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of thing can be used to make words more emphatic, as to simulate how one might pronounce the word in informal speech. The meaning itself doesn't change.

You might see the same thing in English. (`Whoooo is it?`/
`Noooooo!`/
`Suuuure.`)

Answer (score 2):

It's used to make the speaker more childish or cuter. Used a lot when someone closes the eyes of his friend and making him guess who is it.